# Accented characters in R

Tags: r, twitter, encoding, xlsx, emoticons

I'm using R/RStudio on a Windows machine that I purchased in Japan, and I want to input Twitter data (in Spanish) from a social media analysis platform. For example, I have a file in XLSX format containing just two cells:

- RT @PajeroHn @Emerson_182 ya sabía que eras olímpia pero no que eras extorsionador aunque era de esperarse
- Jodas Kevo. A menos que vos seas extorsionador

There are accented vowels in there, as well as some non-standard emoticon characters that didn't make it through the export process intact. I tried this previously using the xlsx package, but it looks like XLConnect might be a better choice:

```
library(XLConnect)
test <- readWorksheetFromFile('test.xlsx',sheet=1,header=FALSE)
```

This is OK; I might even be able to do something useful with the emoticons. I'm bothered that it converts the accented characters (in "sabía" and "olímpia") to their unaccented equivalents:

```
test
RT @PajeroHn @Emerson_182 ya sabia que eras olimpia pero no que eras extorsionador aunque era de esperarse <ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BC><U+009A>
Jodas Kevo. A menos que vos seas extorsionador<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082>
```

My locale is Japanese:

```
Sys.getlocale()
"LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"
```

but changing it actually makes matters worse:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Spanish")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252> 
test <- readWorksheetFromFile('test.xlsx',sheet=1,header=FALSE)
test                                                                                                                                             
RT @PajeroHn @Emerson_182 ya sab僘 que eras ol匇pia pero no que eras extorsionador aunque era de esperarse <ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BC><U+009A>
Jodas Kevo. A menos que vos seas extorsionador<ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082><ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B8><U+0082>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure to specify the encoding for `read.table()`. If you on Windows, it usually assumes "Latin-1" rather than "utf-8" (but that is locale specific i suppose).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
testx2 <- read.xlsx2('test.xlsx',sheetIndex=1,header = FALSE, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: This didn't help; it still returns: Error in sort.list(y) : invalid input 'RT \@PajeroHn \@Emerson_182 ya sabﾃｭa que eras olﾃｭmpia pero no que eras extorsionador aunque era de esperarse 恝ｼ晴・ in 'utf8towcs'.